# Generate matrix of random number with constraints in matlab

Tags: matlab, random, matrix, constraints

I want to generate a matrix of random numbers (`normrnd` with `mean == 0`) that satisfy the following constraints using MATLAB (or any other language)

1. The sum of the absolute values in the matrix must equal `X`
2. The largest `abs(single number)` must equal `Y`
3. The difference between the number and its 8 neighbors (3 if in corner, 5 if on edge) must be less than `Z`

It would be relatively easy to satisfy one of the constraints, but I can't think of an algorithm that satisfies all of them...

### Any ideas?

I am not sure whether to edit my post or to reply here, so I am editing... @MZimmerman6, you have a point. Though these constraints won't produce a unique solution, how would I obtain multiple solutions without using rand?

A very simply 3 x 3 where 5 is the max element value, 30 is the sum, and 2 is the difference
`5  4   3`
`4  4   2`
`3  2   3`

Rody, that actually may help...I need to think more :)

Luis ...Hmmm...why not? I can add up the absolute value of a normally distributed sample...right?

Comment: that is quite the set of restrictions that may void the validity of this being "random", especially the last condition. This would probably better suited for math.stackexchange.com

Comment: NOTE: there are necessarily constraints on the constraints. At least one: `Y < X`, but I'm pretty sure there's one for `Z` as well.

Comment: @MZimmerman6: indeed, it feels a bit like a Sudoku puzzle, doesn't it? :p

Comment: What is the difference between 9 numbers? The center number minus the sum of the 8 neighbours? The max difference between the center and each neighbour?

Comment: @Dan I think he means that `X-N1 < Z`, `X-N2 < Z` etc where `N1`,`N2`, etc are neighbors 1-8.

Comment: Tim, do you have an example matrix that follows these conditions?

Comment: They can't be normal (Gaussian) _and_ have a prescribed sum of absolute values. Your conditions are incompatible

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I've answered your questions in the original post. IF that's okay.

Comment: Because a normal random variable can take _any_ value. It can't be bounded. For example, assume you impose X=10. What do you do if the first generated random number turns out to be, say, 12.7446? See also [my answer in Math StackExchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/713630/generate-matrix-of-random-number-with-constraints)

Comment: Ah I understand. Thus far, my code has been focused on manipulating the generated random variables. Ie. if the max is 12.7446, I can scale the whole matrix down.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an algorithm to get the 'random' numbers that you need.

1. Generate a valid number (for example in the middle)
2. Determine the feasible range for one of the numbers next to it
3. If there is no range, you go to step 1, otherwise generate a number and continue

Depending on your constraints it may take a while of course. You could add an other step to see if changing the existing numbers would help before going back to step 1.